# How should sequential clicks/menu items be formatted?

Tags: discussion, style, formatting

What should the separator be?

- System > Preferences > Keyboard > Layouts > Apply System-Wide
- System → Preferences → Keyboard → Layouts → Apply System-Wide
- System --> Preferences --> Keyboard --> Layouts --> Apply System-Wide
- System | Preferences | Keyboard | Layouts | Apply System-Wide
- System/Preferences/Keyboard/Layouts/Apply System-Wide

Should they be italicized, or quoted?

- Click Edit → Profile Preferences and then uncheck Terminal bell.
- Click *Edit → Profile Preferences* and then uncheck *Terminal bell*.
- Click "Edit" → "Profile Preferences" and then uncheck "Terminal bell".

What precedents are there in the Ubuntu and StackExchange communities?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's anything wrong with the first three. `→` is clearly the nicest character but it's a lot more effort for people to find and insert. I would say that all three are perfectly fine. There's also `»` which is commonly misused around the web (I say "misused" because it's a Spanish quotation mark, not a double-arrow IIRC).

The last two are somewhat less instructive. I read both `/` and `|` as "or" and they don't really show progression (eg click this, ***then*** click this)... But I'm certain people would understand them just as well as arrows.

The Ubuntu documentation writing guidelines defer to the Gnome documentation guidelines and [they state](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gdp-style-guide/2.30/gnome-glossary-user-actions.html.en) that `Applications ▸ Accessories ▸ Calculator` be the standard flow. But again, `▸` isn't a standard keyboard character so I don't think it would be fair to assume that people would use this.

I certainly don't think it's worth the time converting from `>`, `-->` or even `|`  to `▸`. If anybody has a problem understanding, they have the power to comment and quickly ask for clarification. This isn't as static as the distribution documentation.

In short: as long as there's some sort of break between things and the flow makes sense, don't worry about it.

Comment: The «» are called guillemets and are used in several languages: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Guillemets

Answer (score 3):

I believe the first three you have cited are perfectly acceptable:

> - System > Preferences > Keyboard > Layouts > Apply System-Wide
> - System → Preferences → Keyboard → Layouts → Apply System-Wide
> - System --> Preferences --> Keyboard --> Layouts --> Apply System-Wide

Even add

- System -> Preferences -> Keyboard -> Layouts -> Apply System-Wide

We can ask to have  character set be added based to post formatting (IE have -> actually create →) In the end slashes and pipes are really reserved for use in commands on the command line (`/` for paths and `|` for piping). Embedding text in the directions where you draw out the actual path by instructing them to do *this* next only dilutes the instructions more IMO.

Comment: That would be awesome if some agreed-upon code like `-->` was rendered as the ▸ character specified in the [GNOME documentation style guide](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gdp-style-guide/2.30/gnome-glossary-user-actions.html.en).

Comment: I'll check on that.

Comment: maybe the markdown could render it automatically?

Comment: We can have it automatically replaced - however we have to agree upon a set of characters to have replaced.